# Whats the proper way to to link a button to google map?

Tags: javascript, button, google-maps-api-3

I am fairly new to javascript and even newer to google maps api. I want to click a button and have an info window pop up above the marker. I am able to click the marker and have an infoWindow pop up. But If I click an external button it won't work. My ultimate goal is to have the ability to click different buttons and different markers pop up in various places on the map. I'm trying to figure this current problem out because I feel it would aid in my understanding of my future goal. here is my javascript:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413);

    var mapProp = {
        center:center,
        zoom:9,
        //disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(mapDiv,mapProp);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:center,
        map:map,
        title: 'center of new york'
    });

    var content = '<div id="info">' +
            '<img src="uploads/home-bg.jpg" />' +
        '<a href="http://kings.app/blog/6th-woman">' +
        '<p>6th woman</p>' +
        '</a> ' +
        '</div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });


    function position(){
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

here is the html button

```
   <button onclick="position()" id="button"> press</button>
```

I also tried this js code

```
 function position(){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

but it didn't work either. any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the button the function `position` is unknown.

Add a click-listener for the button in `initialize`(`position` is known only there)

```
function initialize() {
    /**
      *..... your code
      **/

    function position(){
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
    //add the click-listener
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('button'),
                                    'click',
                                    position
                                    );
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and remove the `onclick`-attribute from the button

```
<button id="button">press</button>
```

Comment: thank you for your concise answer. I don't understand why this question was down voted. Stackoverflow is for anyone who doesn't know something, has a place to go and find out. The question was within reason.

Comment: You got downvoted because some people are snobbish and downvote without providing a reason. Don't take it personally. I upvoted your question.

Comment: I can't tell you the reason for the downvote, but maybe: Your question is related to a very basic javascript-feature, it's called ***function scope*** (when you like to search for details). Let's assume the downvoter is familiar with javascript, in this case your question might not be good in his opinion( *doesn't show any research effort* ). But I think/know when you are new to a language or even programming at all it's sometimes not so easy to find the correct terms you need to look for, so I think your question isn't bad or good, it's just a legal question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to collect your markers into an array as you're building your map.  In your example, you only have one marker, but I'm assuming you're going to have more.

```
var markerArray = [];
function initialize() {
   ...
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
   });
   markerArray.push(marker);

   ...
} //end initialize

function position() {
   for(i = 0; i < markerArray.length; ++i) {
       google.maps.event.trigger(markerArray[i], 'click');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener from the API itself, like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('press'),'click',position);
```

You don't need an onclick on your button.

Here's how the position() function should look like:

```
 function position(){
   infoWindow.open(map,marker);
 }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/569/)

Answer (score 0):

1. make the marker global so it can be used in HTML click events.
2. use `google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');` to open the existing infowindow.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/neozrs5m/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker;

function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById("googleMap");
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413);

  var mapProp = {
    center: center,
    zoom: 9,
    //disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapProp);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    map: map,
    title: 'center of new york'
  });

  var content = '<div id="info">' +
    '<img src="uploads/home-bg.jpg" />' +
    '<a href="http://kings.app/blog/6th-woman">' +
    '<p>6th woman</p>' +
    '</a> ' +
    '</div>';
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function position() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<button onclick="position()" id="button">press</button>
<div id="googleMap" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```